# Strange image re-size issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, owl-carousel

I am using the Twitter Bootstrat Freelance theme `(http://startbootstrap.com/templates/freelancer/)` and have incorporated Own Carousel.js `(http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/demos.html)`.

All is working well apart from whenever I click an image to view it in a modal window, it appears the wrong size - until I resize my browser window, or refresh the page, or eg press f12. It then seems to 'fix itself'.

Not sure if this is a js conflict issue or I am doing something silly (I am quite new to js). I have looked at the console and can't see any errors, I have also tried different versions of jquery and bootstrap however no difference.

I have created a jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/johnny_s/34L6t/2/
If you view the jsfiddle, try click an image and once it opens in the modal window, resize the screen slightly and you will see what I mean. It somehow suddenly fixes itself.

I would appreciate any help or direction on this issue, as I am trying to create a personal project which needs to be finished quite soon :s

Comment: Mhmm, works for me. Could you describe more detailed, maybe with screenshots, what you mean? If I open the modal (in Chrome), the images seem to be in full witdh..

Comment: Thanks for having a look Sebsemillia. If you click one of the projects, you will see that a new window opens and three images appear one on top of the other. However if you resize the screen at all the images all merge into one and start to scroll (this is what should happen on ititial opening of the window). I'll try to get some screen shots. I'm also using chrome, although tested on ffox and IE.

When you say it works for you, do you mean the images open and scroll as normal?

Comment: No, now I know what you mean. At the moment I also see the three images above each other.. I'll take a look where the problem is..

Comment: Sorry, I tried everything I could think of without success. I think it is somehow connected to the `float: left` for `.owl-carousel .owl-item`. It is just working after the resize, which makes no sense to me. I hope someone else will find a solution, now I'm really interested in it as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for trying Sebsemillia. I have literally been trying all week with no success. I also hope that somebody can fix this issue. So it must be a css issue as opposed to a js issue? Thanks again I appreciate it.

Comment: I'm not sure if it just css, I guess the combination of the BT modal js and the owl-carousel js/css.

Comment: Well I have received some help from the developer but I'm unsure how to implement it. He said - create a event handler for the click event (when the modal opens) and add:

$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel('invalidate', 'all').owlCarousel('update')

Comment: That's the same I tried yesterday. But the resize issue still persists. http://jsfiddle.net/34L6t/6/ (just implemented for the first modal..)..

Comment: I think I may have solved it by using a few extra external js files - see http://jsfiddle.net/uv6fj/5/

Comment: Ah ok, this makes sense. I never used owl-carousel, so I didn't know that it needs even more external js files. Glad you could figure it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to include the following external js files.

Thanks to @Sebsemillia for the help

```
owl.autorefresh.js
owl.autoplay.js
```